# Can I Limit The Moving With svg-pan-zoom?

Tags: svgpanzoom

I'm using svgpanzoom, but movement is unlimited. Is there a way to limit this? I do not want to limit the zoom, I want to limit the movement of svg.

Example:

[image]

After too much moving.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo with how it's possible to implement *pan limit* on [github](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/limit-pan.html)